# Get names of directories containing any .py files

Tags: bash

I have a list of Python files scattered over a directory structure that looks like this:

```
top\py\
    html\
        docs.html
    foo\
        v1\
            a.py
            b.py
    bar\
        v1\
            c.py
            d.py
    baz\
        aws\
            sess.py
```

What I'm trying to here is extract the root directory names of any directories within `top/py` that contain Python files, so `foo`, `bar` and `baz`, using a shell script. Note that there may be files other than Python code here and I do not want those included in the output. I will admit that I'm somewhat of a novice at shell scripting and this is what I've come up with so far:

```
find top/py/. -name *py -exec echo {} \; -exec sh -c "echo $@ | grep -o '[^/]*' | sed -n 3p" {} \;
```

However, the output isn't quite right. This is what I'm getting:

```
top/py/./foo/v1/a.py
foo
top/py/./foo/v1/b.py
foo
top/py/./bar/v1/c.py
foo
top/py/./bar/v1/d.py
foo
top/py/./baz/aws/sess.py
foo
```

It appears that the inner variable to the `grep` is not being updated but I'm not sure what to do about it. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your files don't contain newlines in their names:

```
find top/py -name '*.py' | awk -F / '1; { print $3 }'
```

Otherwise:

```
find top/py -name '*.py' -exec sh -c '
for py_path; do
  pk_path=${py_path%/"${py_path#*/*/*/}"}
  pk_name=${pk_path##*/}
  printf '\''%s\n'\'' "$py_path" "$pk_name"
done' sh {} +
```

For values other than 3, replace `*/*/*/` with as many `*/`s as `n`.